# Using external cab files in WiX

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

All.
How to extract the external cab file?
With node

```
 <Media Id="2" Cabinet="TestCab.cab" Source="Folder\File.cab" EmbedCab="no"/>
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

MSI packages do not support external CAB files. The CABs store only your application binaries. The actual file information is written in the MSI tables.

If you need to include some files in your MSI, you need to add them as regular files. Using an already created CAB won't work.